# Summation theta complexity proof

Tags: summation, asymptotics, computational-complexity

I want to show that $f(n)=\Theta(g(n))$, where
$$
f(n) = \sum_{k=1}^n k^2 2^k,\quad g(n) = n^2 2^n\,.
$$

I know that for $f(n)=\Theta(g(n))$ means there exist positive constants $c_1$, $c_2$ and $n_0$ such 
                 that $0 \leq c_2 g(n) \leq f(n) \leq c_2 g(n)$ for all $n \geq n_0$.

Proving $f(n) \geq c_1 g(n)$ (for $c_1=1$) is trivial, how do I show $c_2g(n) \geq f(n)$?

Comment: After you ask a question here, if you get an acceptable answer, you should "accept" the answer by clicking the check mark ✓ next to it. This scores points for you and for the person who answered your question. You can find out more about accepting answers here: [How do I accept an answer?](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/3286/), [Why should we accept answers?](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/3399/), [What should I do if someone answers my question?](https://math.stackexchange.com/help/someone-answers).

Answer (score 0):

**Hint #1:**

For all $1\leq k\leq n$, $k^2 2^k \leq n^2 2^k$.

**Hint #2:**
$$
\sum_{k=1}^n n^2 2^k = n^2 \sum_{k=1}^n 2^k = n^2\cdot ??
$$